# More efficient way of copying dist files in Grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

New to gruntjs and currently using it for moving some npm distributions to a public/js folder.

Here is the code:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    copy: {
        bootstrapCss: {
            src: "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            dest: "./public/css/bootstrap.css"
        },
        bootstrapTheme: {
            src: "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css",
            dest: "./public/css/bootstrap-theme.css"
        },
        bootstrap: {
            src: "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
            dest: "./public/js/libs/bootstrap.js"
        },
        backbone: {
            src: "./node_modules/backbone/backbone.js",
            dest: "./public/js/libs/backbone.js"
        },
        backboneLocalstorage: {
            src: "./node_modules/backbone.localstorage/backbone.localStorage.js",
            dest: "./public/js/libs/backbone.localStorage.js"
        },
        requireJs: {
            src: "./node_modules/requirejs/require.js",
            dest: "./public/js/libs/requirejs.js"
        },
        underscore: {
            src: "./node_modules/underscore/underscore.js",
            dest: "./public/js/libs/underscore.js"
        },
        jquery: {
            src: "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
            dest: "./public/js/libs/jquery.js"
        },
        requireJsText: {
            src: "./node_modules/requirejs-text/text.js",
            dest: "./public/js/libs/requirejs-text.js"
        }
    }



});

// Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy']);

};
```

Is there any way to make this code smaller, rather than have lots of individual copy commands?

Thanks

Comment: Something like browersify would help with this. As browersify works on the concept of bundling together files mentioned in the ``main`` field of the package.json of the respective package, it would work for your use-case. In case you want to fetch files outside of the ``main`` field of the npm package, you can use transforms like ``browserify-shim`` . Also for bundling CSS , transforms like ``parcelify`` would be helpful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go about this by creating two targets in my `copy` configuration, one for JS and one for CSS. I would use some of the [features](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) provided by Grunt for dynamically building the `files` object to save me from typing and maintaining each destination path. This way, when I want to add files, I need only add their paths to the respective `src` array.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    copy: {
        js: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: './node_modules',
            dest: './public/js/libs/',
            flatten: true,
            filter: 'isFile',
            src: [
                './bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
                './backbone/backbone.js',
                './backbone.localstorage/backbone.localStorage.js',
                './requirejs/require.js',
                './underscore/underscore.js',
                './jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                './requirejs-text/text.js'
            ]
        },
        css: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: './node_modules',
            dest: './public/css/',
            flatten: true,
            filter: 'isFile',
            src: [
                './bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                './bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'
            ]
        }
    }
});
```